# Why the Data of Patient and Doctor are not registred in the database?

Tags: python, html, django

when I register the patient or the doctor on the registration platform (sign up),I don't know why the data of the Doctor and Patient are not registred in the database (MySQL)?, I need your helpe please.

I have the following code in bas_app\views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from .forms import MedForm, PatForm, ContactForm
from .models import Patient, Médecin, User


def accueil(request):
    return render(request, 'base_app/accueil.html')


def inscription(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        dict_inscription_form = {'form': UserCreationForm()}
        return render(request, 'base_app/inscription.html', dict_inscription_form)

    else:
        # Creer un nouveau compte
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:

            try:
                # Enregistrer ses données
                user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                user.save()
                # Se Connecter directement
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'base_app/apres-inscription.html')

            except IntegrityError:
                dict_form_error = {'form': UserCreationForm(), 'error': "Ce nom d'utilisateur existe déjà"}
                return render(request, 'base_app/inscription.html', dict_form_error)

        else:
            # Probléme dans le mot de passe
            dict_form_error = {'form': UserCreationForm(), 'error': 'Le mot de passe ne correspond pas'}
            return render(request, 'base_app/inscription.html', dict_form_error)


# apres Connection page
def apres_inscription(request):
    return render(request, 'base_app/apres-inscription.html')

def apres_connection_medecin(request):
    return render(request, 'base_app/apres_connection_medecin')

# se connecter

def se_connecter(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'base_app/connection.html', {'form': AuthenticationForm()})
    else:
        user = authenticate(request, username=request.POST['username'],first_name=request.POST['nom'],last_name=request.POST['prénom'],password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is None:
            return render(request, 'base_app/inscription.html', {'form': UserCreationForm(),
                                                                'error': "Le nom d'utilisateur ou le mot de passe ne correspond pas"})
        else:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'base_app/accueil.html')


def Medformpage(request):
    if request.method == 'GET' :
        return render(request,'base_app/inscription-finale-medecin.html', {'form' : MedForm() } )
    else :
        try:
            form = MedForm(request.POST)
            newform = form.save(commit=False)
            newform.user = request.user
            newform.save()
            return redirect('accueil')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request,'base_app/inscription-finale-medecin.html', {'form' : MedForm(), 'error' : "Il y a une erreur sur votre soumission"} )


def Patformpage(request):
    if request.method == 'GET' :
        return render(request,'base_app/inscription-finale-patient.html', {'form' : PatForm() } )
    else :
        try:
            form = PatForm(request.POST)
            newform = form.save(commit=False)
            newform.user = request.user
            newform.save()
            return redirect('accueil')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request,'base_app/inscription-finale-patient.html', {'form' : PatForm(), 'error' : "Il y a une erreur sur votre soumission"} )
```

I have the following code in bas_app\models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

spécialité_types = [
    ('', 'Choose....'),
    ('Aucune','Aucune'),
    ('chirurgien','chirurgien'),
    ('Gynécologue','Gynécologue')
]
sex_types = [
    ('1','Homme'),
    ('2','Femme'),
]

quartier_types = [
    ('0', ' '),
    ('1', 'Hay Riad'),
    ('2', 'Hassan 2'),
    ('3', 'Agdal')
]

class Médecin(models.Model):
    username_id = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nom = models.CharField("Nom ",max_length=30)
    prénom = models.CharField("Prénom ", max_length=30)
    cin = models.CharField("C.I.N ", max_length=10)
    date_de_naissance = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    spécialité = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=spécialité_types, default='spa')
    sexe = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=sex_types, default='1')
    quartier = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=quartier_types, default='0')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Patient(models.Model):
    username_id = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nom = models.CharField("Nom ",max_length=30)
    prénom = models.CharField("Prénom ", max_length=30)
    cin = models.CharField("C.I.N ", max_length=10)
    date_de_naissance = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    sexe = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=sex_types, default='1')
    quartier = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=quartier_types, default='0')
```

I have the following code in bas_app\forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from django.forms.widgets import NumberInput
from .models import Médecin, Patient

YEARS=[x for x in range(1950,2010)]
sex =[
      ('', 'Choose....'),
      ('Femme', 'Femme'),
      ('Homme', 'Homme'),
]
quartiers=[
    ('', 'Choose....'),
    ('Riad_agdal', 'Riad_agdal'),
    ('Hassan', 'Hassan'),
    ('Alfath', 'Alfath'),
]
spécialité_types = [
    ('', 'Choose....'),
    ('Aucune','Aucune'),
    ('chirurgien','chirurgien'),
    ('Gynécologue','Gynécologue')
]

class MedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Médecin
        fields = [ 'nom', 'prénom', 'cin', 'sexe', 'date_de_naissance', 'quartier', 'spécialité']
        widget={'nom': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'First_name'}),
                'prénom' :forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Last_name'}),
                'cin' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'CIN'}),
                'sexe':forms.Select(choices= sex),
                'date_de_naissance' : NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
                'quartier':forms.Select(choices= quartiers),
                'spécialité' :forms.Select(choices= spécialité_types)
                }

class PatForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ['nom', 'prénom', 'cin', 'sexe', 'date_de_naissance', 'quartier']
        widget = {'nom': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First_name'}),
                  'prénom': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Last_name'}),
                  'cin': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'CIN'}),
                  'date_de_naissance': NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
                  'sexe': forms.Select(choices=sex),
                  'quartier': forms.Select(choices=quartiers)
                  }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think your `def inscription` is just not right, google some signup examples and see the difference

Answer (score 0):

Change home redirect to what ever page you want to redirect to.

The name of the page comes from the `urls.py`. Ex: `path("", Home, name="home")`

Try this :

```
def inscription(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
                user = authenticate(username=form,password=password)
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('home')
    else:        
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'base_app/inscription.html', {'form': form})
```